# Embedding and HTML document in another: how do I make it auto-size?

Tags: html

I have a bunch of html help files and my boss wants them to be all in one giant file as well, for printing. I want to just embed them all into a single html page and I need the `<object/>` to auto-size to fit the entire page *within* the page.

doing it this way:

```
<object type="text/html" data="My.html"/>
```

Open to doing it another way if anyone has better suggestions, but this is just a real simple task so I want to keep it as simple as I can.

Thanks all!

EDIT:
This is all the html I'm using just for testing purposes.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>

    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Default</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe  style="height:100%;width:100%" src="test.html"/>
    </body>

    </html>
```

The embedded document:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Default</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
<object style="width:100%;height:100%;" type="text/html" data="My.html"/>
```

That works for me (IE 9.0, Firefox 7.0.1).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Yatrix : and what about using an iframe instead of an object ?

Comment: Again, width but no height using an iFrame and your edit (I tried that before).

Comment: @Yatrix:testing with what navigator ?

Comment: IE 9. Writing it in MS Express Web 3, if that matters.

Comment: @Yatrix:tested on the same version, without any strange extension installed. Works really fine, width and height. Clear your cache twice, exit twice, restart. Eventually change My.htm by anything else to prevent cache load, same thing for main html file,.

Comment: It didn't work. Included all of the html I just made to test it from scratch.

Comment: @Yatrix : Well... I don't know what to say. I've tested it with the same navigator than you, even with Firefox and it works. Could you perhaps put your files somewhere so I can test them from my navigator to see if the problem is your configuration ?

Comment: I'd be happy to email them to you. I don't have any place to put them for you to download, though. I find it very strange that width works but height won't.

Comment: Yah. I've tried with multiple files, renamed them, cleared cache.

Comment: @Yatrix:just make 2 files, a.htm and b.htm. In the first one just put `<object style="width:100%;height:100%;" type="text/html" data="b.htm"/>` and in the second just put a sequence of text. Nothing else. There is no reason that would not work. I've tested it right now again with another IE version. That still works.